# How am I reading out of the bounds of my array?

Tags: arrays, c, printf, scanf

I'm writing a program that will have a command prompt where the user can infinitely input command strings and I will process them as needed.

I have a command-line limit of 200 characters, but for now, I am performing a hello world test with a limit of 4 characters per command to see how my system would handle an input overflow. To my absolute surprise and confusion, I'm seeing that even though I am declaring my `command[5]` input array as to only allocate 5 characters, I am able to write outside those bounds and read `command[7]` without getting any exception or runtime error. In the example below, I input `hello world` as a command and reading `command[7]` returns the letter `o` which is the correct answer (I was expecting an error after trying to read outside the 5 character bound of my array).

Can someone explain what's going on? How can I make sure that the input gets truncated as I was expecting when the user goes over the buffer size that I've established?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char command[5]; //commands can't be longer than 4 characters
   char c;
   while (1)
   {
       printf("# "); //print command prompt
       scanf("%[^\n]4s", command); //read command
       while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
       {
           /*discard overflow input*/;
       }
       printf("received command: %c\n", command[7]); //echo character from command
       if (strcmp(command, "exit") == 0)
       {
           break;
       }
       memset(command, 0, sizeof(command)); //clean command buffer
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not have any automatic bounds checking. Accessing outside the bounds results in Undefined Behaviour. UB means the result is unpredictable - could crash, could return wrong values, could even appear to "work". And behaviour may change at any time. It is up to you as a C programmer to prevent UB conditions from occuring.

Comment: Note that `scanf("%[^\n]4s"` will read a string up to a newline and then must match `"4s"`. The format `%[]` is not a subset of `%s`, but entirely different. Try `scanf(" %4[^\n]"` (with leading space too). And what is the "overflow input" you are kludging away? You already read up to newline. The leading space will filter the previous newline.

Comment: me . I would read the line using getchar, not a combination of scanf and getchar. Or via readline

Comment: No, don't kludge it with `getchar()` at all. Just use `scanf` the way it is intended, or with `fgets()`

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification on reading out of bounds. I didn't know that I shouldn't always expect an error. @WeatherVane your suggestion of putting the input limit ```4``` in front of my new line formatter worked like a charm, thanks! And as a clarification, the reason I'm discarding overflow input in the inner while loop is that, if the user goes over the character limit, scanf will only copy up to the char limit into my command buffer, but on the next iteration of the loop, it will pickup whatever was left in the stdin.

Comment: Also, you should be checking the return value from `scanf()`.  You need to know whether the input operation succeeded or not.  Especially with the blank missing in `" %4[^\n]"`, you could easily have failures because the newline is left behind in the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard doesn't specify what happens when you access memory outside of what you've allocated. It could read correctly, it could read something else (if something that owns that memory overwrites it, it could cause a segmentation fault (if you access memory outside of your program's allocated space).

One option would be to use the width modifier on `scanf` to ensure you receive at most 4 characters:

```c
scanf("%4s", command);
```

Answer (score 1):

As multiple people mentioned in the comments and other answers, the C standard establishes that accessing memory outside the allocated bounds results in undefined behavior, but that doesn't mean it will always give an error. I guess that was an interpretation error by me.

Regarding the specific issue I was having where scanf was reading more than 4 characters, the advice provided by @Weather Vane in the comments worked well. All that was needed was changing my scanf command.

From this: `scanf("%[^\n]4s", command); //read command`

To this: `scanf("%4[^\n]s", command); //read command`

This way, scanf will only write up to 4 characters into the buffer `command`, and the contiguous memory will be left untouched. Therefore, if I try to access command[7], I would get garbage or possibly an error.

For anyone wondering about the while loop that discards overflow, see the comment section.

Comment: While `scanf("%4[^\n]s", command);` is much better than your first attempt, it's still rather strange. Ask yourself: What is the `s` at the end of the string actually doing? Sure that is what you want...

Comment: And you should probably include a blank before the `%` — there are three conversion specifiers that do not skip white space, namely `%c`, `%n` and `%[…]` (scan sets).  All the other conversion specifiers do skip white space.  And note that scan sets end at the `]`; anything after that is either a literal character or the `%` of a new conversion specification.